# hide menu bar for full screen apps with applescript

Tags: applescript

This applescript code by user regulus6633 works great for toggling the "Automatically hide and show the menu bar on desktop" system preference in macOS 12.1:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell dock preferences to set autohide to not autohide
end tell
```

Does anyone know how to do the same for "Automatically hide and show the menu bar in full screen"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same is not applicable to the **Menu Bar** as with the mentioned **Dock** *preference* and as such you can use **UI Scripting** to achieve the goal.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Monterey** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open to Dock & Menu Bar

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal pane "com.apple.preference.dock"

--  Toggle the Automatically hide and show the menu bar in full screen checkbox.

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        tell window 1
            repeat until exists (first checkbox whose title is "Automatically hide and show the menu bar in full screen")
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            click (first checkbox whose title is "Automatically hide and show the menu bar in full screen")
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
delay 0.2
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Comment: works great, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shortcut that I wrote to toggle Hide Menu Bar between "Never" and "In Full Screen Only" Hope this helps!

```
on run {input, parameters}
    ## This script toggles the hide menu item setting from "Never" to "In Full Screen Only"
    ## Used the great UI Browser https://pfiddlesoft.com/ app (now no longer operational) to write
    ## confirmed to work for MacOS 14.2.1, but they are changing the control center layout quickly
    ## Archon Fung on December 22, 2023
    
    ##open the system settings app in background
    do shell script "open -j x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.ControlCenter-Settings.extension"
    
    tell application "System Events"
        
        tell application process "System Settings"
            ## set CurrentShowStr to "Never"
            ##get value of pop up button 1 of group 9 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Control Center"
            delay 1
            set CurrentShowStr to value of pop up button 1 of group 9 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Control Center"
            if (CurrentShowStr is "Never") then
                set NewShowStr to 3 ##In Full Screen Only 
            else
                set NewShowStr to 4 ##Never
            end if
            tell pop up button 1 of group 9 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Control Center"
                click
                ##need delays to allow the menu items to populate
                delay 0.5
                click menu item NewShowStr of menu 1
                delay 0.5
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit application "System Settings"
    return input
end run
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!  I'm getting a
error "" number -1721
When running this in macOS 14.2.1

Comment: Are you putting that code into the ShortCuts app? I should have been clear - code above is for Shortcuts, not Script Editor…